# Rails ActionController::TestCase how to set the controller class explicitly

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Controller Test Class file that differs from the name of the original Controller Class

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
end

class MyControllerNotLoggedTest < ActionController::TestCase
end
```

When I run the tests I have this error:

```
RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 6 looks like it is like this:

```
class MyControllerNotLoggedTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests MyController
end
```

- https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionController/TestCase#label-Controller+is+automatically+inferred